# Is there any application for design physics for coccos2d game development?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am new comer in iOS game development, I want to know that is there any mac or windows application available for design scenes , and physics of iOS game development.

like http://maniacdev.com/2011/05/tool-cocosbuilder-drag-and-drop-scene-builder-for-cocos2d/

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Try this application [LevelHelper and SpritHelper](http://www.levelhelper.org/)

Comment: It's fine but is there any other free application available like that ?

Comment: hmmm i am also waiting for its free demo version :)

Answer (score 2):

check this out:

cross platform editor based 2D game development tool.

http://vimeo.com/23291628

http://gamebuilderstudio.com/

Comment: I want only for iOS cocos2d game davelopment